# Creating a custom confirm dialog using ajaxConfirmMessage in octobercms

Tags: octobercms

I need some help here on how to create custom confirm dialog using `ajaxConfirmMessage` instead of he default browser confirm as from the documentation it say.

> **ajaxConfirmMessage**    triggered on the window object when confirm option is given. The handler gets 2 parameters: the event object and text message assigned to the handler as part of confirm option. This is useful for implementing custom confirm logic/interface instead of native javascript confirm box.

I have this now

```
$(window).on('ajaxConfirmMessage', function(event, message) {
    // Stop the default confirm dialog
    event.preventDefault();

    // Okay Button
    $('#okay-button').click(function() {
        // Resolve the deferred object, this will trigger whatever was being confirmed
        event.promise.resolve();
    });

    // Cancel Button
    $('#cancel-button').click(function() {
        // Reject the object, this will cancel whatever was being confirmed
        event.promise.reject();
    });

    // Return a value so the framework knows we're handling the confirm
    return true;
});
```

Got that from googling about it.

This is my button

```
 <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" data-request ="onDelete" data-request-success="alert('Successfully Deleted')" data-request-data= "record: {{ post.id }}">Delete</a>
```

I just need some guidance on how to make this work using a bootstrap modal that shows the `okay` and `cancel` button. I am thinking that is how it should work, or if there is a better way to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow this code structure it will work for you.

> I am adding basic structure here you can modify it as you like. I am just creating a page and adding this code directly to the page.

- Make sure your layout has `{% scripts %}` so added `js script using {% put scripts %}` will append to the end of page.
- I am assuming `jQuery and bootstrap-Js` already available on page.

### 1. Page's HTML section

```html
<div class="container">    
    <!-- Button -->
    <button 
        type="button" 
        class="btn btn btn-primary" 
        data-request ="onAjaxCall" 
        data-request-success="alert('Successfully Deleted')" 
        data-request-confirm="test-msg"
    >
        Confirm
    </button>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="okay-button">Ok</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel-button">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% put scripts %}
<script>
    $(window).on('ajaxConfirmMessage', function(event, message) {
        // Stop the default confirm dialog
        event.preventDefault();    

        // open our own bootstrap modal
        $('#myModal').modal('show'); 

        // Okay Button. we will unbind if any events are attached to it first
        // reattach click event - this is required as this code will call each time
        $('#okay-button').unbind().click(function() {        
            // hide modal
            $('#myModal').modal('hide'); 
            // Resolve the deferred object, this will trigger whatever was being confirmed
            event.promise.resolve();
        });

        // Cancel Button
        $('#cancel-button').unbind().click(function() {        
            // hide modal
            $('#myModal').modal('hide'); 
            // Reject the object, this will cancel whatever was being confirmed            
            event.promise.reject();        
        });

        // Return a value so the framework knows we're handling the confirm
        return true;
    });
</script>
{% endput %}
```

### 2. Code section to just return dummy success response.

```php
function onAjaxCall() {
    return ['result' => 'All Good!'];
}
```

> It will show you `bootstrap modal as confirm dialog`.

If any doubts please comment.

Comment: glad to see its straightforward and helped you :)